# Could not load type from assembly (the executable)

Tags: c#, mono, typeloadexception

This works fine in Windows, but when trying to run in Mono I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'WLBot.LobbyBot.LobbyBot[]' from assembly 'WLBot, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[WLCommon.Matches.MatchSetupDetails,WLBot.LobbyBot.LobbyBot].InitArrays (Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[WLCommon.Matches.MatchSetupDetails,WLBot.LobbyBot.LobbyBot].Init (Int32 capacity, IEqualityComparer`1 hcp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[WLCommon.Matches.MatchSetupDetails,WLBot.LobbyBot.LobbyBot]..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WLBot.Client.WLBotClient..ctor (System.String url, System.String botid, System.String secret) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WLBot.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'WLBot.LobbyBot.LobbyBot[]' from assembly 'WLBot, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[WLCommon.Matches.MatchSetupDetails,WLBot.LobbyBot.LobbyBot].InitArrays (Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[WLCommon.Matches.MatchSetupDetails,WLBot.LobbyBot.LobbyBot].Init (Int32 capacity, IEqualityComparer`1 hcp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[WLCommon.Matches.MatchSetupDetails,WLBot.LobbyBot.LobbyBot]..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WLBot.Client.WLBotClient..ctor (System.String url, System.String botid, System.String secret) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WLBot.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

This is a bit infuriating as the class is actually compiled into the exe, not separate like in a dll. All of the answers I've seen have been about trying to load types from libraries.

Even if I re-create the class in the project the same thing happens. I'm very confused as to why this is happening. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "Even if I re-create the class in the project the same thing happens." - what does the debugger say?

Comment: @Maarten This exact same error, not much more information when the debugger breaks. Not quite sure what other info you might want from it. It breaks when the dictionary is created.

Comment: Can you show the code? What dictionary are you talking about?

Comment: @Maarten I don't know exactly what part of the code would be relevant, I have a dictionary like this: `private Dictionary<MatchSetupDetails, LobbyBot.LobbyBot> Bots = new Dictionary<MatchSetupDetails, LobbyBot.LobbyBot>();`

Comment: I have the namespace specifier because the namespace name is the same as the class name, however I've tried it with different unique namespace and class names and the same thing always happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer for the OP but for future googlers, I had this problem for binaries compiled on Windows and copied to the Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (jessie).

Similarly, running on Windows was fine.

The affected version of Mono (built from tarball) was `4.6.0.125/753c323`.

The fix was to upgrade to `4.6.1.5/ef43c15`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems really interesting for you scenario: [Mono-LibreOffice System.TypeLoadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029620/mono-libreoffice-system-typeloadexception)

The answer quoted:

> The .NET framework has a true just-in-time compiler. Mono doesn't, it has an AOT (Ahead Of Time) compiler. In other words, it aggressively compiles all the code in the assembly, not just what is about to be executed.

So instead of trying to understand the line of code (your constructor), try to think what else you might be calling. He used the `var` instead of declaring the variable types itself. This would prevent Mono advancing ahead of time in your process and let it decide the type when you execute.

Hope it helps you debug your code.

Comment: Sadly you can't use type `var` in a class definition. Any other ideas?

Comment: @ChristianStewart Where are you running? Is it a Ubuntu machine? Try creating a blank mono project with just a `Main` console app that make single calls to each library you are referencing in your app. Check if that happens. Try using var for variables too. If some mono library is missing you should know.

Comment: No mono libraries are missing. Normal mono programs work fine, including incredibly complex ones I've written in the past. Its just this one dictionary definition in the class that's having problems. I can't use var type because it's a class property.

Comment: Well.. my last guess on this `AOT` matter is: try do disable it ([check here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/aot/#limitations)). Sorry...